# Bind server for external site

Tags: bind, internal-dns

I have a bind running on a Ubuntu server and I would like to use it instead using host files. I my quite inexperienced at bind and am having a lot of trouble with it. Right now the bind server is working for internal dns and was an external DNS server before but has been retired from that. I have followed the tutorial [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-bind-as-a-private-network-dns-server-on-ubuntu-14-04) and haven't been able to get it to work. Is there an easier way DNS entries in bind? I mostly run clearOS for my routers and they just have a simple way to add a host with the host name and a ip address.

So what I would want to do is take the hostname westappps.cable.comcast.com and point it to the ip 10.168.220.220. Is there a way to do this without making a zone for it?

```
/etc/bind/named.conf.local
//
// Do any local configuration here
//

// Consider adding the 1918 zones here, if they are not used in your
// organization
//include "/etc/bind/zones.rfc1918";

include "/etc/bind/rndc.key";

view "internal" {
match-clients {
    lan_hosts;
    };
recursion yes;

// prime the server with knowledge of the root servers
zone "." {
    type hint;
    file "/etc/bind/db.root";
};

// be authoritative for the localhost forward and reverse zones, and for
// broadcast zones as per RFC 1912
zone "localhost" {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/db.local";
};
zone "127.in-addr.arpa" {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/db.127";
};
zone "0.in-addr.arpa" {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/db.0";
};
zone "255.in-addr.arpa" {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/db.255";
};
zone "trizonllc.com" {
    type master;
    file "/var/lib/bind/trizonllc.com.internal.hosts";
    };
zone "gotrizon.com" {
    type master;
    file "/var/lib/bind/gotrizon.com.internal.hosts";
    };
zone "trizon.com" {
    type master;
    file "/var/lib/bind/trizon.com.internal.hosts";
    };
zone "8.168.192.in-addr.arpa" {
    type master;
    file "/var/lib/bind/db.192.168.8";
    allow-update {
        key rndc-key;
        };
    notify yes;
    };
zone "cable.comcast.com"{
    type master;
    file "/var/lib/bind/cable.comcast.com.internal.hosts";
};
};
view "external" {
match-clients {
    !lan_hosts;
    any;
    };
recursion no;

// prime the server with knowledge of the root servers
zone "." {
    type hint;
    file "/etc/bind/db.root";
};


zone "trizonllc.com" {
    type master;
    file "/var/lib/bind/trizonllc.com.hosts";
};
zone "spectraseven.com" {
    type master;
    file "/var/lib/bind/spectraseven.com.hosts";
};
zone "doelevate.com" {
    type master;
    file "/var/lib/bind/doelevate.com.hosts";
};
zone "frontiersalessupport.com" {
    type master;
    file "/var/lib/bind/frontiersalessupport.com.hosts";
};
zone "gotrizon.com" {
    type master;
    file "/var/lib/bind/gotrizon.com.hosts";
};
zone "trizon.com" {
    type master;
    file "/var/lib/bind/trizon.com.hosts";
};
zone "teltanium.com" {
    type master;
    file "/var/lib/bind/teltanium.com.hosts";
};
zone "transynergydirect.com" {
    type master;
    file "/var/lib/bind/transynergydirect.com.hosts";
};
zone "trizonstall.com" {
    type master;
    file "/var/lib/bind/trizonstall.com.hosts";
};
zone "czncorp.com" {
    type master;
    file "/var/lib/bind/czncorp.com.hosts";
};
zone "trizonllc.net" {
    type master;
    file "/var/lib/bind/trizonllc.net.hosts";
};
zone "spectraseven.net" {
    type master;
    file "/var/lib/bind/spectraseven.net.hosts";
};
zone "redrk.com" {
    type master;
    file "/var/lib/bind/redrk.com.hosts";
};
zone "redrocc.com" {
    type master;
    file "/var/lib/bind/redrocc.com.hosts";
};
zone "getredrock.com" {
    type master;
    file "/var/lib/bind/getredrock.com.hosts";
};
zone "maxguardid.com" {
    type master;
    file "/var/lib/bind/maxguardid.com.hosts";
};
zone "gotritech.com" {
    type master;
    file "/var/lib/bind/gotritech.com.external.hosts";
    };
zone "cooleypro.com" {
    type master;
    file "/var/lib/bind/cooleypro.com.external.hosts";
    };

zone "amerihomesgroup.com" {
    type master;
    file "/var/lib/bind/amerihomesgroup.com.hosts";
    };

zone "cable.comcast.com"{
    type master;
    file "/var/lib/bind/cable.comcast.com.hosts";
};
};
```

/var/lib/bin/cable.comcast.com.local

```
$ttl 3600
cable.comcast.com.  IN  SOA 69.252.81.81 (
        42
        900
        600
        86400
        3600 )
        NS  ns02.cable.comcast.com.
        A   10.0.0.123  
westapps        A   10.168.220.220
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include your bind configs.

Comment: Refer to the BIND documentation on how to create a zone, zonefile, and so on. If you're getting errors, please post relevant excerpts from your logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I have figured it out. I used command `named-checkzone example.com /etc/bind/db.example.com`
to check my file and it gave me these errors:

```
/var/lib/bind/cable.comcast.com.hosts:9: ignoring out-of-zone data (ns02)
/var/lib/bind/cable.comcast.com.hosts:12: ignoring out-of-zone data (westapps)
zone cable.comcast.com/IN: has no NS records
zone cable.comcast.com/IN: not loaded due to errors.
```

To fix the ignoring out-of-zone data errors I added the FQDN of each and restarted bind. I still am not using the DNS servers that Comcast has setup but this should solve my problems. Here is my finished zone file.

```
$ORIGIN .
$ttl 3600
cable.comcast.com.      IN      SOA cable.comcast.com. admin.cable.comcast.com. (
                        42
                        900
                        600
                        86400
                        3600 )
                        NS      ns02.cable.comcast.com.
ns02.cable.comcast.com. A       69.252.81.81
westapps.cable.comcast.com.     A       10.168.220.220
erone.cable.comcast.com. A      10.165.55.140
```

I hope this can help someone else.